# Google Maps API for Work customers not working

Tags: php, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My client purchased Google Maps API for Work customers with 100,000 requests per 24 hour period and 10 requests per second. The google map is working fine and users are shown on map.

[image: Google maps showing users]

But sometimes ithe users are not populated on map. Shows an empty map.
[image: Empty map. Not showing users]

**I already enabled Geocoding API,Google Maps JavaScript API v3,Places API. But it still showing 2500 requests available in total. But Google Maps API for Work customers with 100,000 requests**

[image]

Iam using the below code

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$_SESSION['userlat'].",".$_SESSION['userllong']."&sensor=false&key=XXXX-XXXXX&callback=initialize";
$details=file_get_contents($url);       
$geocodedinfo = json_decode($details,true);
```

**The status code returns is OK**

```
$obj = json_decode($details);
$GeoStatus=$obj->{'status'};
```

I dont know what the problem was. Do i need to activate other api in console?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given license `client`-ID and `signature` must be supplied, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth

Comment: But it says **The Places API and Geolocation API do not use the client and signature parameters. These APIs use a key parameter, obtained from the API Console** @Dr.Molle

Comment: You request the **geocoding**-service, not the **geolocation**-service.

Comment: Whether this clientid and signature available for **Google Maps API for Work customers**?? and is there any difference between **Google Maps API for Work customers** and **Google Maps API for business**